# Firestore web multiple posts under same uid

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[Firestore reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7tF6.png)I fixed most of my other issues but what I've been stuck on for today is figuring how to get a user to have multiple posts under the same uid.
Each post is under the, Post:"", field and everything I tried didn't work. Any tips or solutions?

```
const textToSave = inputTextField.value;
docRef.collection("ask").doc(user.uid).add({
  Post: textToSave
}).then(function () {
  console.log('saved')
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log('error');
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to `add()` a document to a document, which is not valid. Documents can only be added to collections. You could do something like:

```js
docRef.collection("ask")
  .doc(user.uid)
  .collection("posts")
  .add({Post: textToSave})
```

or you could store multiple posts in an array inside the same doc, something like:

```js
docRef.collection("ask")
  .doc(user.uid)
  .update({
    posts: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({Post: textToSave})
  })
```

Comment: Ohh I understand the first one completely. But if they both have the same 'field value title' (Post:), wouldn't that cause some sort of error? And I'd upvote your comment but I only have 1 reputation on here.

Comment: When you do `add()` it automatically creates a new document with a random ID. `add()` is essentially a shortcut for `.doc().set({...})` where `doc()` is a reference to a new doc with an auto-generated ID.